# How to import a json file using angular and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to import a local json file into an angular application. I do not want to use http. I know there are several other questions about this but nothing I have tried seems to work. I ran npm install typescript to get the latest version. The file is definitely there because VisualStudioCode gives me a selection list when editing.

The data is in the form:-

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10}
  ]
}
```

I have tried:-

```
import mydata from '../mydata.json';
```

and

```
import * as mydata from '../mydata.json';
```

and

```
import {default as mydata} from '../mydata.json';
```

and

```
import mydata = require('../mydata.json');
```

with

```
// ./tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

which generally give the compile error cannot find module mydata.json apart from the require() which tells me to use one of the first three I tried.

I am using D3 so I have tried

```
d3fetch.json("../mydata.json, function(error, data)
```

which gives the runtime error 404 not found [http://localhost:4200/mydata.json]

Comment: did you check this? https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

Answer (score 0):

This MVCE:

```
// main.ts
import file from './file.json';
console.log(file);

// file.json
{ "hello": "world" }

// index.d.ts
declare module '*.json' {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Can do this:

```
> tsc
> node main.ts
{ hello: 'world' }
```

Perhaps you should add the json declaration file.

I'd also suggest another way: adding the webpack [json-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/), and including 'json' to [`module.exports.resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions) in `webpack.config.json`.

Note that every JSON is a valid JS file - if this file is not use by other entities, you can replace its extension by .js and add `export default { "nodes": ...` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: That also worked, thanks. Any idea why the resolveJsonModule in typescript 2.9 doesn't work as it is supposed to?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I am getting an error .data(mydata.links) does not exist on typeof "*.json". 
Presumable I need to modify the typings.d.ts to be more exact but not sure how to change it to reflect my data structure.

Comment: It should not happen, according to the declaration file above, you declare anything that `typeof "*.json"` is `any` so no `property doesn't exist` error should be thrown. Can you link an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that I can observe your codebase?

Comment: Also please upvote and/or validate any answer that works

Comment: Its a bit complicated to do an MVCE as its in  the middle of a force directed graph app. Its complaining about links property not existing. I fixed it by splitting the json into two files, one for nodes and one for links

Comment: I've validated your answer thanks. Really I'd like to know the correct way to do a declare module for my data structure i.e ones that includes the "links" and "nodes" identifiers.

Comment: So now it's all stopped working as I restarted ng serve (angular) and got unknown compiler option resolveJson module!

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
var mydata = require('../mydata.json');
```

Method 2 :
Add below lines inside compiler options in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    ...
  }
}
```

and then try as below:

```
import * from '../mydata.json';
```

Method 3:

Use HTTP call

```
this.http.get(`../mydata.json`).subscribe((resp: any) => {
   console.log(resp)
});
```